# MongoDB outbound channel overrides document in DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring integration to update DB with the values that arrive in a message.

An inbound channel queries the Mongo DB, the resultset has to be updated with the status that it is being processed.

The flow works, but I dont get the expected behavior.

I was expecting that the messase handler, `MongoDbStoringMessageHandler` will eventually do an upsert, but it seems it is completely overriding the object in the DB with the message payload.

The payload does not have all the fields that are present in the DB.

Is there some configuration that I am missing ?
Or is this not a typical use case ?

Below is my configuration :

Inbound message source

```
@Bean
    public MessageSource mongoMessageSource(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory) {
        MongoDbMessageSource mongoDbMessageSource = new MongoDbMessageSource(mongoDbFactory,
                new LiteralExpression(new BasicDBObject("status","test").toString()));
        mongoDbMessageSource.
                setCollectionNameExpression(new LiteralExpression("BankAccountDetail"));
        mongoDbMessageSource.setEntityClass(AccountBalanceDetails.class);
        return mongoDbMessageSource;
    }
```

The output channel for the above source

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mongoInboundChannel(MessageSource messageSource) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(messageSource).
            channel("messageChannel")
            .get();
}
```

The output channel:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel messageChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

The main flow:-

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fromDirect(@Qualifier("messageChannel") MessageChannel messageChannel,
                                  AccountBalanceTransformer accountBalanceTransformer,
                                  MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, AccountBalanceUpdater accountBalanceUpdater) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(messageChannel).split().
            handle(accountBalanceUpdater, "update").
            //handle(System.out::println).
            handle(mongoOutput(mongoDbFactory)).
            get();
}
```

The outbound message handler

```
@Bean
public MessageHandler mongoOutput(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory) {
    MongoDbStoringMessageHandler mongoDbStoringMessageHandler = new MongoDbStoringMessageHandler(mongoDbFactory);
    mongoDbStoringMessageHandler.setCollectionNameExpression(new LiteralExpression("BankAccountDetail"));
    return mongoDbStoringMessageHandler;
}
```

Here is my model class:-

```
@Document(collection = "BankAccountDetail")
```

public class AccountBalanceDetails {

```
private String id;
private String status;
private String message;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "AccountBalanceDetails{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", status='" + status + '\'' +
            ", message='" + message + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it be writing a custom message handler.

```
    public class CustomMongoMessageHandler extends AbstractMessageHandler {

            @Autowired
            private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

            @Override
            protected void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
                AccountBalanceDetails accountBalanceDetails = (AccountBalanceDetails) message.getPayload();
                Query basicQuery = new Query();
                mongoTemplate.updateFirst(basicQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.
                   where("id").is(accountBalanceDetails.getId())),
                        Update.update("status", accountBalanceDetails.getStatus()),
                        AccountBalanceDetails.class);
            }
        }
```

Instead of using this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fromDirect(@Qualifier("messageChannel") MessageChannel messageChannel,
                                  AccountBalanceTransformer accountBalanceTransformer,
                                  MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, AccountBalanceUpdater accountBalanceUpdater) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(messageChannel).split().
            handle(accountBalanceUpdater, "update").
            handle(mongoOutput(mongoDbFactory)).
            get();
}
```

I now use:

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fromDirect(@Qualifier("messageChannel") MessageChannel messageChannel,
                                      AccountBalanceTransformer accountBalanceTransformer,
                                      MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, AccountBalanceUpdater accountBalanceUpdater,
CustomMongoMessageHandler customMongoMessageHandler) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(messageChannel).split().
                handle(accountBalanceUpdater, "update").
                handle(customMongoMessageHandler()).
                get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It really does `upsert` for existing doc, but since you provide a whole doc you end up with overriding all it properties according the provided fields.

You can consider to use `MongoDbOutboundGateway` (`MongoDb.outboundGateway()` for Java DSL) with an appropriate `CollectionCallback`:

```
/**
 * Reference to an instance of {@link CollectionCallback} which specifies the database operation to execute.
 * This property is mutually exclusive with {@link #query} and {@link #queryExpression} properties.
 * @param collectionCallback the {@link CollectionCallback} instance
 * @param <P> the type of the message payload.
 * @return the spec
 */
public <P> MongoDbOutboundGatewaySpec collectionCallback(CollectionCallback<P> collectionCallback) {
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/mongodb.html#mongodb-outbound-gateway

Comment: My actual use case is to get a document from Mongo and pass it via a few transformers, only the first transformer gets the original DB object, rest of the others get another Object that have the id of the DB object and other fields. When an error comes,I create the POJO object of the DB collection and set the id, received from the message and the status as error. When I send this partially created object to mongo outbound channel, I get the behavior defined in the question.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that I dont provide any other properties except for status and id. I dont have the rest of the fields when the exception might come

Comment: Right, that's why I suggest to perform the same `partial update` that you do in your custom code via mentioned `CollectionCallback` in the `MongoDbOutboundGateway`